# string array not converting to url in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, url

I have a array which is declared as below var photoarray = String The values which are in the photoarray is as follows:

```
["https://res.cloudinary.com/dtwvevtm7/image/upload/v1606166095/wdfub3plecnhmixbwtgw.jpg", " https://res.cloudinary.com/dtwvevtm7/image/upload/v1606166095/dbzvkv8qhtwhgbocuzwb.jpg"]
```

Since it is an array, it is passed into for loop and this string is converted to URL. When it is converted to url, it is showing

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

The code which is used to retrieve the url is as follows:

```
for i in 0..<self.photoarray.count
{
    let url = URL(string: self.photoarray[i])
    print("url is", url)
    self.images.append(LightboxImage(imageURL: url!))
}
```

It is showing the first value of the array when url is printed, but the next value is showing `nil`. What is the issue?

Comment: See Mohammad’s answer re extraneous spaces. FYI, if you want to convert an array of strings to an array of URLs, I might suggest `compactMap`, e.g.:`images = photoarray.compactMap { URL(string: $0) }`. Or, if you know your strings might have whitespace, if you can’t clean them up before adding them to the array, you can clean them up as you build the array of URLs, e.g. `images = photoarray.compactMap { URL(string: $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a blank space in the first character of your second url string in the `photoarray`. Remove it. `URL` initializer returns nil if the string doesn’t represent a valid URL.
Also its better not using force unwrapping here.

Comment: Thanks it worked.couldnt upvote due to less reputation